# Injective resolution of representable sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a scheme and consider the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ of sheaves of abelian groups on the fppf site over $S$. It is known that $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives. My question is: given a representable sheaf , say $\mathbb{G}_m$, I'm wondering if we can explicitly construct the first few terms of an injective resolution that are representable. In other words, can we have an exact sequence of abelian sheaves $1 \to \mathbb{G}_m \to \mathcal{I}_0 \to \mathcal{I}_1 \to \mathcal{I}_2$ where $\mathcal{I}_i$ are representable for $i=0,1,2$?